# how to add items from a List to a GenericMenu (Editor Window) and you can only select one

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I am working in Unity using the UnityEdior library. I made a custom editor window and I am filling in the void OnGui(). I created a list that takes all the string version of the names of the branches from my git repository like this

```
void OnGUI()
{
    Process checkbranch = new Process();
    if (GUILayout.Button("Show Branches"))
    {
        checkbranch.StartInfo.FileName = "git";
        checkbranch.StartInfo.Arguments = "branch";
        checkbranch.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        checkbranch.Start();
        checkbranch.WaitForExit();

        Branches.Clear();
        string branch;
        branch = checkbranch.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
        while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(branch))
        {
           var m = new CheckBranch();
           m.BranchName = branch;
           Branches.Add(m);

           branch = checkbranch.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
         }
     }
}

public class CheckBranch
{
     public string BranchName;
     public bool BranchBool;
}
```

and now im trying to add these branches to the generic menu so there will be a drop down menu where you can chose the branch you want to switch to. So based on that statement it means that you can only select one branch from the generic menu.

Then I tried adding them to the menu and here where it starts to not work.

```
private void OnGui()
{
...
if (GUILayout.Button("test"))
        {
            GenericMenu menu = new GenericMenu();
            for (int i = 0; i < Branches.Count; i++)
            { 
                menu.AddItem(new GUIContent(Branches[i].BranchName), Branches[i].BranchBool, Toggle); 
            }
            menu.ShowAsContext();
        }
}
void Toggle()
    {
        Process p = new Process();

        for (int i = 0; i < Branches.Count; i++)
        {
            Branches[i].BranchBool = true;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "git";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = $"checkout {Branches[i].BranchName}"; // menu function
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.Start();
            p.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
```

So when I select one of the branches it selects all how do I work around this.

here are the photos from unity 
[before pressing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zW50h.png)

[after pressing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJaGb.png)

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something more like a combo box. [`EditorGUILayout.Popup`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.Popup.html) sounds exactly like what you are looking for.

Try this in the GUI Layout:

```
string[] options = new string[movParamsListSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < movParamsListSize; i++)
            options[i] = i.ToString();
movStepToMoveTo.intValue = EditorGUILayout.Popup("movementStepToMoveTo",
      movStepToMoveTo.intValue, options, EditorStyles.popup);
```

This is like a combo box with the options you specify in the options string[].
See movementStepToMoveTo field, which is a Serialized property:

[image]

Hope that is useful.

Comment: You could then enhance this with by wrapping it in `EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck(); .... if(EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck()){ CHECK THE NEW INDEX AND DO YOUR THING HERE }`

Comment: The `EditorStyles` is a bit redundant btw. a `Popup` by default already **is** a pop-up ;)

Comment: I would also keep it as a `List<string>` in order to add and remove items and then do `options.ToArray()`

Comment: @derHugo how do I make it from a list?

Comment: @crimson as said use a `List<string>` as usual (`Add` & `Remove` items) and then use `options.ToArray();` in order to convert it to an array only in the moment where you need it as array